# git-svn branch - How to keep branch in sync with trunk?

Tags: branch, git-svn

There are plenty of questions about git-svn workflow, but I haven't been able to figure this one out:

[This section of the svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchemerge.basicmerging.stayinsync) talks about a common practice with SVN: you make a branch, and you keep merging changes from the trunk as the trunk gets updated, so that the branch always includes the latest changes.

I did `git svn branch` to create a branch on svn and then set up a tracking branch to work on it. [These](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266395/git-svn-how-do-i-create-a-new-svn-branch-via-git) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192736/how-do-i-make-git-svn-use-a-particular-svn-branch-as-the-remote-repository) cover the process pretty well.

Now suppose there were changes made to the trunk, which I now want to merge into the branch. What is my best option? Note that I need to keep git-svn happy, and not mess up the work of people using the branch with subversion, so just doing a rebase would probably not work.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582348/using-git-svn-pull-merge-or-rebase) seems to talk about a similar situation, although it's pretty old, and I'm not sure what the bottom line there was - it seems to suggest I should `git checkout master` and then `git rebase mybranch`, but that can't be right.

I suspect the the answer should be something that has the effect of `svn merge`, preferably with setting the `mergeinfo` property, but alas, there is no `git svn merge`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand how this simple question was left unanswered for more than a week, with only 13 views so far. I guess it was my fault, bad question writing.

Anyway, I figured it out myself. Short version: just use `git merge` instead of `git rebase`.

My confusion came from using `git rebase` when syncing a branch with the changes in master. When working on local branches, this usually works great, and keeps the history clean. However, [you should not rebase commits that you have pushed to a public repository](http://progit.org/book/ch3-6.html#the_perils_of_rebasing), and the subversion repository is (apparenly) public enough. `git merge`, on the other hand, works beautifully, and doesn't have any problem.

So, the long answer is: when you want to merge the latest changes in the trunk into the svn branch you're tracking, just do:

```
git merge master
# Handle conflicts, git add when you're done
git commit
git svn dcommit
```

This will keep your branch in sync with trunk, but will not set mergeinfo, so you probably should not mix `svn merge` with this kind of practice.